# Como filtro componentes de una señal wav

Tags: matemáticas, matlab

Poseo este codigo:

> > [s Fs]=wavread('P.wav');
> >
> > L=length(s);
>
> >
>
> > %plotea la señal sin filtro en el rango de la frecuencia
> >
> > NFFT = 2^nextpow2(L);
> >
> > S = fft(s,NFFT)/L;
> >
> > f = Fs/2*linspace(0,1,NFFT/2+1);
> >
> > plot(f,2*abs(S(1:NFFT/2+1)));

El me genera resultados buenos. Sin embargo ahora quiero eliminar ciertos componentes de mi señal, he buscado usar filtro Butterworth o chebyshev pero no se como usarlos.

Answer (score 0):

Primero necesitas calcular los coeficientes del filtro, i.e.
     [b, a]=butter (n,Ws )
Luego aplicas el filtro
     DatosFiltrados=filter (b, a, datos)